The meaning of "奪耳" in 《說文解字》
When I looked up the meaning of the character "卅" () in 《說文解字註》（段註本）, the text was as follows, as shown in the picture: "
Translate: 我在《说文解字注》（段注本）中查「卅」（古作「」）一字时，其解释如下如图：

，三十幷也。古文省。【此亦當云省多。奪耳。古音當先立切。七部。今音蘇沓切。】凡之屬皆从。


I don't understand the meaning of the phrase "奪耳". I can only literally understand it as "making the ears-like object disappear" (使失去耳状物). But this obviously doesn't make sense in the sentence, at least I don't know what this ears-like object is.
Translate: 我不能理解「奪耳」这个词的意思，只能​​从字面上理解为「使失去耳状物」。但这在句子中显然是说不通的，至少我不知道这个像耳朵的东西是什么。


「奪」 is short for 「奪誤」, which is jargon meaning Shape omissions or corruptions during publishing and transmission of ancient texts (抄刊古書而形成的文字脫漏或訛誤).
「耳」 is the classical sentence-termination modal particle, meaning that's all (罷了，而已).


This commentary describes Duàn Yùcái's presented opinion on the character 「」. The quote

古文省。此亦當云省多*。奪耳。
*「多」 is a superfluous character here, and should be omitted as part of the interpretation.

should be translated to

In ancient texts, this is Simplified1.This is also2 deemed to be a simplification. It is a textual corruption which occurred through the transmission of ancient texts through the ages.

where

"Simplified" is Duàn Yùcái's presented opinion for the ancient variants of 「卅」, which are joined at the bottom like this (see glyph evolution table):

Duàn Yùcái's opinion is that, since 「卅」 is made of 3 「十」 side-by-side, in ancient texts the joining of the bottom in the 3 「十」 into 「丗」 means that the ancient forms are "simplifications" (省), and is a corruption from transmitted published texts (奪誤).

"Also" refers to Duàn Yùcái's commentary on the previous entry, 「廿」. In that entry, it is first argued that joining of the bottom in 「廿」 (instead of having them separate, like 「卄」) is a "simplification" (省) in ancient texts.



References:

《漢語大詞典》
季旭昇《說文新證》


@dROOOze 的回答 关于「奪耳」二字本身的解释是十分确切的，作为题主（OP），我十分感谢他的回答。但是对于一些细节的部分，比如「奪」在语境中的意思等，我有一些和他不同的看法。
段的注文的意思
我认为，段玉裁 的这段对《说文解字》的注文

此亦當云「省多」。奪耳。

的意思是：

「省」注1应该作「省多」注2解释。这是誊抄古书时的脱漏注3。

注1：「省」：就是前文（也是《说文解字》原文）「，三十幷也。古文省。」的「省」。

注2：省多：省略一下多的字注2.1。这里指将「三十」两个字并为一个字。
注2.1：文字最早是刻在竹简上被记录的，挺麻烦的。将两个字并为一个字，是为了省事。

注3：是说这里将「省多」中的「多」漏写了，成了「省」了，本来原文按理应该作「古文省多」的。


这里的 注2 和 注3 与 @dROOOze 所提出的是不同的。
「古文省」的用法和「省多」的意思
在《说文解字》中，多次出现「古文省」，举例如下：

得，，古文省彳。


云，，古文省雨。

如上这两个例子中，「古文省〇」是指这些写法省略了一些结构「〇」。
如 @dROOOze 所指出的那样，最关键的是对「廿」字的解释：

廿，二十幷也。古文省多。【省多，省作「二十」㒳字爲一字也。】

其中中括号「【】」中的内容是 段玉裁 对原文的注文。再结合 段玉裁 对「」的注文，可见，段玉裁 认为，「」应该也和「廿」类似，是「省多」（两个字并为一个字）。
观点不同处的总结
@dROOOze 的回答中，

将「省」归结于「卅」「廿」两个字中下面是否要有一横（笔画结构）。
我不认同这个观点，理由是：

段玉裁 已经明确说了「省多」的意思：


省多，省作「二十」㒳字爲一字也。


在《说文解字注》一书中，「卅」字的构型只有「」一种，并未出现「卅」或者「丗」。「廿」字同理，只有「廿」这一种构型，没有提及如「卄」的形式。所以归结于下面是否有一横缺乏实据，较为牵强。


认为「省多」中的「多」这个字在这里是多余的，在解释的时候应该忽略掉（我应该没有误解他的这个描述的意思，他的意思应该不是「『多』这个字在『省多』中的释义是『多余的』，意思是『省略多余的』」）。我不认同这个观点，理由是：

「古文省」一般不会单用，就是说不会这三个字前后都有句读，如「，三十幷也。古文省。」一样。这大概是因为单用会造成歧义，比如将「古文省」理解为「古文中写作『省』」或者「古文中是『省』的意思」，所以（段玉裁 说）应该作「古文省多」。所以「多」这个字不是多余的。
仍然见上文 段玉裁 的注文：省多，省作「二十」㒳字爲一字也。所以在这个角度上，将「省多」这个词看作 段玉裁 自己定义的一个专有名词就可以了。
如果「多」字是多余的可以忽略，那么这段注文就变成了「古文省。此亦當云省。」，这就不通了，显得后一句话「此亦當云省。」是多余的了。另，如果按照 @dROOOze 的回答，是为了突出这个类比「廿」字词条的「亦」字，那么根据「廿」字词条的说法「廿，二十幷也。古文省多。」，「省多」这个词以及「多」这个字是有意义的。


认为「夺误」在语境中的意思是，在字的下面，古文中和书中有一横的笔画结构之差。我不认同这个观点，理由是：

上面也提到的，对于「」「廿」，《说文解字》中只提出了一种文字构型。
解释为「将『省多』中的『多』漏写了，成了『省』」或许更贴合一些。



我认为我的解释更合理一些，敬请批评指正。再次感谢 @dROOOze 的回答。

I think @dROOz's answer has covered your question about "奪耳 - meant corruption)", and in addition, he also addressed "省(simplified)" and "省多". If you disagree, you should not have "accepted" but simply "uptick" the answer for his effort.

@r13 ，就本问题核心的部分（「夺耳」在语境中的意思）而言，@dROOOze 1 回答了「夺耳」的意思，并耐心地2.结合上下文做出了对此的解释。我是对他的2.持不同观点，而他提出的1.可以说是极为贴切的、无可争议的。
在这个问题中，我认为1.的重要性远远大于2.，这是从零到一的突破，很大程度上启发了我。这是我在理性上（在提出对2.的不同见解之后，仍然选择）accepted 他的回答的原因。

Thanks for the clarification. now I understand better. But it still seems odd, you as the OP, to place own pinions in the answering box though.

@r13 ，我不是太能明白您的后一句话的意思，我试图从我的角度说明这件事情：我认为我给出的这篇 Answer，可以构成对这个问题的回答（如我上面所说的 2.，我提出了如何按照上下文理解「夺耳」。这是不可或缺的一部分，虽然没有 1. 重要），因此选择回答是合适的。从而，我认为以 Answer 的形式发表我的这个观点，比在 dROOOze 的回答中进行评论，或者 Edit Question 进行补充，都更适合。
另外，我不是明知故问（虽然在 Can I answer my own question? 里面，这也是合理的），如果您是这个意思的话（恕我冒昧揣测）。我的这个 Answer 中的观点的形成，得益于我对 dROOOze 的回答的思考，尤其是在其启发下阅读了《说文解字注》的「廿」词条，并非在提出问题之初便有这个想法（那时候我连「夺」代表「夺误」这件事都不知道）。

感謝花功夫仔細批了我的答案！StackExchange 不太適合論壇式來回討論，所以我認爲用這答案的内容問個新問題（列如：段玉裁《說文解字注》中解的「卅」字如何分析？）較好。

When you disagree with something addressed in the answer to your question, you can express your disagreement by writing an opinion in the "Comment" box, not in the "Answer" box, because 1. your opinion is not an answer, but a dispute. 2. the opinion wasn't concerning your opening question but something besides it.

@r13 ，我想我刚才已经强调过了「我给出的这篇 Answer，可以构成对这个问题的回答」，因此选择 Answer 是合适的。原因在于，我的这个 Answer 中，我给出了结合上下文的「夺耳」的解释。这是对 Question 的正面的回答的一个部分，并且是一个新的观点，构成 Answer 操作的条件，所以说可以选择 Answer，而不是只是在别人的回答下、或在问题的评论区下进行评论。另外，我的反对的观点和理由比较长，我无法在评论所限定的字数内表达清楚，再加上还有图片等，所以没有选择评论。

"「我给出的这篇 Answer，可以构成对这个问题的回答」".  to which I disagree, but I cease my case.
